# Value of one variable, where two other variables are equal in R

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns

I am still quite new to R and I have a simple (I guess) question: I would like to divide the value in one column (variable `Sum_Output`) in the first year of a program by the value in the same column in the second year of a program.
I have identified the first and the second year. Now I fail to tell R

"Use the value of column 6 where Year = Firstyear and divide it by the value of column 6 where Year=Secondyear."

I tried the following approach, but get the error, that

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

So I guess, this operation does not achieve to only calculate the ratio for those rows, where the condition is fulfilled. How could I include this in my approach or do you have an easier way to calculate the ratio of sum_outputs in the first and the second year?

Thanks a lot for your time and ideas how to do this!

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("Program A", "Program A", "Program A", 
                              "Program A", "Program B", "Program B", "Program B", "Program B", 
                              "Program C", "Program C", "Program C", "Program C", "Program D", 
                              "Program D", "Program D", "Program D"), Year = c(2019, 2020, 
                                                                                  2021, 2022, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2019, 
                                                                                  2020, 2021, 2022), Input = c(0, 14, 10, 7, 0, 11, 20, 6, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                               3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6), Firstyear = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                                                                                                                2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022
                                                                                                               ), Secondyear = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
                                                                                                                                 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
                                                                                                                                 "NA"), Sum_Ouput = c(0, 50, 70, 80, 0, 70, 12000, 6, 0, 0, 40, 
                                                                                                                                                      50, 0, 0, 0, 50)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

Threshold <- 0.1
data$EF_Outlier <- ifelse(data[data$Year == data$Firstyear, "Sum_Ouput"]/data[data$Year == data$Secondyear, "Sum_Ouput"] < Threshold,  1, 0)
```

Comment: That is a warning, not an error message.

Comment: `data$Year == data$Firstyear` is true on 4 rows, `data$Year == data$Secondyear` on 3 other rows. What of this 7 rows should have divided values?

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have an additional problem when I apply the approach on the original data, I guess because of NAs in the Sum_Output and NaN in First and Second Year:  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, EF_Outlier, value = c(0, NA, 0, 0,  : 
  Ersetzung hat 142 Zeilen, Daten haben 1272

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what the question *really* wants.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

divide <- function(x) x/dplyr::lead(x, default = NA_real_)

Threshold <- 0.1

data %>%
  arrange(ID, Year) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(EF_Outlier = ifelse(Year == Firstyear, divide(Sum_Ouput), Inf),
         EF_Outlier = as.integer(abs(EF_Outlier) < Threshold))
#> # A tibble: 16 × 7
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>    ID         Year Input Firstyear Secondyear Sum_Ouput EF_Outlier
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>      <int>
#>  1 Program A  2019     0      2020 2021               0          0
#>  2 Program A  2020    14      2020 2021              50          0
#>  3 Program A  2021    10      2020 2021              70          0
#>  4 Program A  2022     7      2020 2021              80          0
#>  5 Program B  2019     0      2020 2021               0          0
#>  6 Program B  2020    11      2020 2021              70          1
#>  7 Program B  2021    20      2020 2021           12000          0
#>  8 Program B  2022     6      2020 2021               6          0
#>  9 Program C  2019     0      2021 2022               0          0
#> 10 Program C  2020     0      2021 2022               0          0
#> 11 Program C  2021     3      2021 2022              40          0
#> 12 Program C  2022     6      2021 2022              50          0
#> 13 Program D  2019     0      2022 2022               0          0
#> 14 Program D  2020     0      2022 2022               0          0
#> 15 Program D  2021     0      2022 2022               0          0
#> 16 Program D  2022     6      2022 NA                50         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks great! It definitely goes in the right direction. Yet, it has a couple of problems for my case: 1. If I have a NA in the Sum_Output in the previous year, it seems to deliver a 1 (i.e. outlier). 2. The lead of the Firstyear is not always the Secondyear (as this variable is defined as the 2. year, where input is positive, which is not always the case in the year after introduction).  And I think, I have to arrange by Year, right?

Comment: @CathiP As for 1. and 3. (arrange by ID and Year), see if it is corrected. As for 2., in the posted data all `Input` is positive, maybe with an example data set with those cases I will be able to correct the code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to put together a larger example data set, which has all the specifics of the original data set!